# Multiple installs of Ruby -- how to solve in OS X

Tags: ruby, macos, rubygems

I'm having problems with Ruby scripts finding the right gems. It seems this is related to having multiple installs of Ruby on my system. OS X already comes with Ruby but it's not the latest one. I upgraded from Snow Leopard to Lion and suddenly have all these instances of the rubygems folders:

```
 /Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.6.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems
 /Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.7.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems
 /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rubygems-update-1.8.11/lib/rubygems
 /Library/Frameworks/MacRuby.framework/Versions/0.10/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.2/rubygems
 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems 
 /Users/[user_name]/.rvm/repos/ruby/lib/rubygems
```

I installed the graph gem with `gem install` and I can't seem to find it in any of these locations. irb finds it when I do a `require` but a ruby script saved and run from the CLI produces the error:

> 'require': no such file to load

Another clue is that when running `rails server` I often see output from `/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/`

But the graph gem doesn't seem to be in that path either.

So, yes a big mess. Any help to safely simplify this and remove the redundant instances would be greatly appreciated.

**Update:**

Was able to track the installed gems to:
`/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/Current/usr/lib/ruby/user-gems/1.8/gems`

So should I just delete everything else with a `rm -rf`? I'd hate to do that and cause all sorts of dependency problems. Ultimately I'd like to end up with a clean system with only one ruby install but I cannot wipe out my hard drive.

Comment: Removed ruby-on-rails tag, added osx tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend you use rvm to switch rubies and gems. put a .rvmrc into your project folders and it will switch a "gemset" automatically for you.

The general consensus is to leave the ruby version of the os as it is an use either rvm or rbenv to switch ruby versions.

It does look like you have rvm installed as well as multiple ruby installation installed in different ways too.

Does rvm work correctly, if so you can ignore your other ruby installations.

Comment: But will it find the installed gems in the other folders? (see edit above, I discovered the location of the user installed gems). Also how do I switch the gemset automatically? What needs to go into the .rvmrc?

Comment: in .rvmrc you put a line in like so `rvm use gemsetx@ruby1xx` you have to add that ruby then add a gemset to it. the rvm tutorials should help you do that.

Comment: yeah gemsets are like a blank slate for a particular ruby version.

Comment: Ah, yes, that is much better, with rvmrc and gemset things are looking good. Would you recommend I delete the other locations? It's just very confusing to have all these versions lying around but I don't want to break any dependencies, especially for any MacRuby stuff Xcode might have. Thanks a lot!

Comment: it wouldn't hurt to keep them all.